# Ignore row if all 4 cells are 0; get name if any of the 4 cells is greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

i have a list of names(Column A), the numbers in columns B to F are result of a formula. I'm trying to create a FOR LOOP code that will check columns B to F, if all cells in B to F are zero then the code should ignore the current row and skip to the next row; if any of the cells in columns B to F is greater than 0, then the code should get the corresponding name in Column A.

**Example:** *If any of the cells in B2, C2, D2, and E2 is greater than 1, then i should get the name/value of A2. if all cells in B2, C2. D2, and E2 are all zeros, then proceed to check next row and do the same thing.*

here's the code i used to try to get the names that has any of the 4 column cell values greater than 1

```
     For i = 2 To LastCalcAnalystRowIndex '//wsCalculations.Cells(Rows.Count, "CP").End(xlUp).Row

    '//Get Component from cell in column "BP"
        Analyst = wsCalculations.Cells(i, "CP").Value
        Component = wsCalculations.Cells(i, "CN").Value
        weeknumber = wsCalculations.Range("BR2").Value + 3

            If wsCalculations.Cells(i, "B").Value = 0 And wsCalculations.Cells(, "C").Value = 0 _
            And wsCalculations.Cells(i, "D").Value = 0 And wsCalculations.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 _
            And wsCalculations.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then
            Exit For
            Else
            wsCalculations.Cells(i, "A").Value = wsCalculations.Cells(i, "CP").Value
            End If
            Next
```

using the code above, i tried to get the names which all 4 column values are not equal to zero, but the result i get is just a copy of the original list. i highlighted the rows i want my code to skip. i also included the result i get and the result i want to get. 
Below is a sample data. My original data has 54 rows. [image: data].
can anyone please tell me what im getting wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real need for VBA.

Note that I have used a Table with structured references.  You can change it to a range with normal references if you prefer.

If you have O365, you can use a helper column and a formula.

Add a helper column which `SUM`'s the cells in each row (and you can hide that column if necessary).

```
eg:  G2:  =SUM(Table3[@[Column2]:[Column6]])
```

Then, assuming the data is in a **Table** named `Table3` use the formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Table3,Table3[sumRow]>0),0,1)
```

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you can use:

```
I2: =IFERROR(INDEX(Table3[Column1],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Table3[sumRow]>0)*ROW(Table3)-ROW(Table3[#Headers]),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

and fill down the length of the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution but could shorten your initial code

Why not create a hidden column* that does an =SUM of the entire row

Then get the value from that

instead of using code to get the value of each 5 cells then adding it up.

edit: changed the 'hidden cell' to 'hidden column' :P

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngSum As Range
    Dim wsCalculations As Worksheet
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim n As Long

    Set wsCalculations = ActiveSheet

    With wsCalculations
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each rng In rngDB
        Set rngSum = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 5)
        If WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngSum) > 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = rng
        End If
    Next rng

    With wsCalculations
        If n Then
            .Range("h2").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
        End If
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone please tell me what im getting wrong?

actually your shown code isn't consistent with your wording, so it's impossibile to tell all that's wrong

but for sure that `Exit For` is a logical error, since it actually gets you out of the loop when it first meets five zeros

so as far as this logical error is concerned, you should change that piece fo code to the following:

```
With wsCalculations
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 5), 0) < 5 Then ' when a row is eligible for math

            ' do your math

        End If

    Next
End With
```

where I used `WorksheetFunction.CountIf()` function that enables you to deal with different conditions since your wording wasn't clear about this item, too (*"greater than 0"*, *"all cells...are zero"*, "*greater than 1"*)